# C# Console Application program to Create a user defined matrix and find Lowest number

Tags: c#, matrix

**Write a C# Console Application program to Create a user defined matrix which takes no of rows & columns and values
& find lowest number & it accept only numeric if user enter other than numeric it warn user to enter numeric only.**

For Ex:

*Enter no of Rows: (system)

2(user)

Enter no of Columns: (system)

2(user),

Enter row  value1: 20

Enter row value 2: 4

Enter column value1: 30

Enter column value2: 20

Lowest number is: 4

please help me how to solve this ex.*

Comment: Seems like homework. Have you tried something? What do you have on your mind? Post some code and we'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this outside your "main" method to get make sure the user gives a number.

```
private static int GetNumber(string request)
{
    bool succeeded = false;
    Console.WriteLine(request);
    string reply="";
    while(!succeeded)
    {

        reply = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            int.Parse(reply);//Attempt to convert "reply" into an integer.
            succeeded = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request+" (make it a number)");
        }
    }
    return int.Parse(reply);
}
```

And then use this for your main method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int rows = GetNumber("Enter no of Rows:");
    int columns = GetNumber("Enter no of Columns:");
    int[,] matrix = new int[rows,columns];
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            matrix[row,column] = GetNumber("Enter value for sector Row: "+(row+1)+" Column: "+(column+1));
        }
    }
    int smallestnumber = matrix[0,0];
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            if(matrix[row,column] < smallestnumber)
            {
                smallestnumber = matrix[row,column];
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest number is: "+smallestnumber);
}
```

I took a liberty here as your example says "Enter row value 1...Enter column value 2" however each individual value in a matrix would be represented by both a row and a column.

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that request code but put forth no effort.  SO is not a code-writing service - please don't encourage those who seem to think it is.

Comment: I corrected the "matrix" array, just in case you wonder why the previous code doesn't work :p

Answer (score 0):

First you have to a create matrix which takes the dynamic value; then takes two for loops: i,j; then take one temparary varible; stores the first value in the given array and then compares all the values in the array to the temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't indicate a specific part you were having trouble with but it seems checking user input for int could be tricky. Here's what I did to check if user inputted value is a number:

```
string row;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows");
        while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out row) == false)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You selected {0} rows", row);
```

I would also use something like a generic list of type int instead of a matrix since you don't know at the beginning how many elements the array will contain. A generic list allows you to add items to the list with no issue and you can even use

```
int max = MyList.Min();
```

to find the lowest number which is super easy.